# Вопрос по парсингу

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

В html коде страницы есть:

[image]

В парсере в список контента я добавляю item таким образом:

```
hero = item.find('td', class_='cell-xlarge').get('data-value')
```

На выходе ошибка:

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Что нужно исправить, как правильно спарсить значение `data-value`?
Полный код [тут](https://github.com/MrRomaninTR/Pars/blob/master/dota_matches_pars.py)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1232236/420098/edit))

Comment: Элемент `data-value` не содержится в html, он добавляется скриптами.

Comment: Так и как спарсить значение data-value, если скриптами добавляется? Код (одна строчка) в виде скриншота, потому что так нагляднее, и его не скопируешь из кода страницы.

Comment: item.find('td', class_='cell-xlarge')['data-value'] так пробовали?

Comment: Если с ['data-value'] то 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @RomanRomanin смотреть, откуда скрипты берут его. Или поискать в HTML другое место, где есть эти данные. В общем скачайте страницу через requests и в ней смотрите, в браузере много дорисовывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы получаете `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` из-за того, что `items = soup.find_all('tr')` находит все строки, в заголовке таблицы в том числе, а в нем нет `'td' class_='cell-xlarge'`. Можно или взять только элементы из тела таблицы:

```
items = soup.find('tbody').find_all('td', class_='cell-xlarge')

for item in items:
    print(item.text)
```

или оставить ваш вариант, но сделать срез без первого элеманта:

```
for item in items[1:]:
    print(item.find('td', class_='cell-xlarge').text)
```

Оба варианта выводят имена:

```
Pudge
Juggernaut
Lion
...
Elder Titan
Visage
Chen
```

Если есть необходимость вытащить все значимые данные, можно собрать все строки в tbody таблицы и перебирать в них td, примерно так:

```
rows = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    tds = row.find_all('td')
```

Итоговый код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/played?date=month'
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    tds = row.find_all('td')

    name = tds[1].text
    matches = tds[2].text.replace(',', '')
    pick_rate = tds[3].text
    win_rate = tds[4].text
    ratio = tds[5].text

    print(f'{name:20} matches: {matches}, pick: {pick_rate}, win: {win_rate}, ratio: {ratio}')
```

будет выводить на печать:

```
Pudge                matches: 4621108, pick: 25.76%, win: 50.54%, ratio: 2.25
Juggernaut           matches: 3875575, pick: 21.60%, win: 53.37%, ratio: 3.24
Lion                 matches: 3863652, pick: 21.53%, win: 50.25%, ratio: 2.05
...
Elder Titan          matches: 271008, pick: 1.51%, win: 49.75%, ratio: 2.45
Visage               matches: 231091, pick: 1.29%, win: 51.09%, ratio: 3.16
Chen                 matches: 100342, pick: 0.56%, win: 46.51%, ratio: 2.36
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось с первым, остальные колонки спарсить не получается, у них одинаковые параметры: td data-value ...

Comment: исправил код в исходном сообщении. Подскажите пожалуйста, как быть с остальными колонками?

Comment: @RomanRomanin с остальными - так же: парсить )) добавил в ответ